# Use of training and test set on 10-Fold Cross-Validation

Tags: cross-validation, dataset

I would like to know if the following assumption is correct:
"In the 10-Fold Cross-Validation we use 100% of data set for the training and 100% of data set for the test"

For the training I'm sure we can say yes, but for the test? 
I think that for each iteration, if we use different 10% part of data for the test, at the end of the iteration we will have used the entire data set as a test set. It is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $k$-fold CV, each of the $k$ splits is used as test set once. Thus, each data point is part of a test set once. So if this is what you mean by '100% of data set for the test', then you are right.